# Flask - CSS turns HTML texts invisible on app

Tags: python, html, css, flask, frontend

This is a weird problem which I have been getting when linking my html file to a css file. I am running the app using Flask on PyCharm.

```
**static\style.css**
body { 
    color: #fffa;
}
```

```
**templates\base.html**
...
<link rel="stlyesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css')}}">
...
<body>{% block content %} {% endblock %}</body>
```

```
**templates\home.html**
{% extends 'base.html' %}
...
{% block content %} example {% endblock %}
```

As a result, the string 'example' is printed on the website as I am able to highlight it but it appears to be "invisible" as I cannot see the texts without the manually selecting them (i.e., the screen is just blank perhaps due to  text being white?) but I cannot prove the latter because even when I change the color in css to black or red it just remains invisible.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @Bn.F76 thanks for concern but issues been resolved now; with that said, I take it you probably had to same solution as was necessary in my case. I fixed this by 'disabling cache' in the network tab (within the developer's console/window in google chrome). Nevertheless, an odd problem.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is working as it should be. `#fffa` will be treated probably as your browser as white(ish). And you are applying it to whole `body`.
And if background color is set to white too (and probably it is by default) - then you can't see text.

If you want to see black text - you should set it to `black` or `#000`.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#Basic_colors

Comment: tried setting it to other colours still same issue.

Comment: can you share your repository?